# Remove section from table of contents but keep its auto number

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

[image]

How to remove subsection from table of contents
but keep its auto number?

\subsection*{SubSection1} removes from table of contents and auto number.

Comment: duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399941/keep-sections-in-place-for-numbering-but-hide-from-pdf-and-toc

Comment: No, this is not an answer to the question.
Such method hides all subsection title, 
but I need to hide subsection in TOC keeping auto number of subsection.

Comment: You didn't read the other one closely enough then, because the answer shows how to (a) remove it from the TOC, (b) assign a number to it, and (c) control whether to display or hide it in the main document text.

Answer (score 1):

I try to work it out by patching `\subsection` to get a new command `\mysubsection`. Then you can use `\mysubsection` to get a numbered section which would not appear in the contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\let\my@sect\@sect
\let\my@startsection\@startsection
\let\mysubsection\subsection
\xpatchcmd{\my@sect}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
      \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
  } {%
} {} {}
\xpatchcmd{\my@startsection}{\@sect}{\my@sect}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\mysubsection}{\@startsection}{\my@startsection}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\mysubsection{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\mysubsection{test}
\subsection{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]